# Is it possible to add many children with the same name without rewriting the existing one in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would to know if is it possible to add field to a child that already contains the same field?

[image]

Specifically, I have this database and I would like to add the fields address, latitude and longitude many times whenever the user wants without rewriting the field already contains the value.
Thanks in advance to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Inside one child you can't have two fields with the same name. What you can do is to add, let's say, `address1`, `address2`, fields. Or use a list of address values. But having multiple fields with the key `address` is not an option.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that I don't know how many times the user could add those fields so it would be expensive to create many copies of those fields. About the list, could you tell me more or give me some examples?

Comment: You can use List<String> to store all address values from the user. Each time he adds new you retrieve the List from firebase, add new value, and save it back. Check Firebase documentation on saving values as List or HashMap, whatever works better for you.

Comment: Thank you very much